# Using Router Annotations with other routes in Phalcon

Tags: php, annotations, router, phalcon

Is it possible to use annotations on top of regular routes in Phalcon. For example, I have this:

```
$router->add('/', [
                'module' => 'home',
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'index'
            ])->setName('home');

$router->notFound([
                'module' => 'home',
                'namespace' => 'Home\Controller',
                'controller' => 'error',
                'action' => 'show404'
            ]);

            foreach ($app->getModules() as $key => $module) {


                    $router->add('/'.$key.'/:params', [
                        'module' => $key,
                        'controller' => 'index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                        'params' => 1
                    ])->setName($key);

                    $router->add('/'.$key.'/:controller/:params', [
                        'module' => $key,
                        'controller' => 1,
                        'action' => 'index',
                        'params' => 2
                    ]);

                    $router->add('/'.$key.'/:controller/:action/:params', [
                        'module' => $key,
                        'controller' => 1,
                        'action' => 2,
                        'params' => 3
                    ]);

            }

            $router->addModuleResource('api', 'Api\\Controller\\Index', '/api/index');
            $router->addModuleResource('api', 'Api\\Controller\\Client', '/api/client');
```

The problem is that the router annotations that I define near the bottom don't seem to work, probably because the routes to /api/index and /api/client have already been defined above.

Also, at the same time, is there a way to define a notFound for a module? Basically, if I'm at some URL that starts with /api/, I would like it to go to an error page in my api module. Otherwise, it should go to error page in the regular module.